# complex query fetching latest inserted data from mongodb to compare with indexed data in array

Tags: mongodb, nosql, d

I'm trying to construct middleware-code in d-lang that reads an array of struct DATA from a connected POSIX named pipe and identify changes by comparing with existing data, if changes occurred add the changed struct data into db.

Struct is constructed like this and all variables are likely to be changed

```
struct DATA
{
    char[20] name;   
    int_16 sect;    
    int_16 ptyp; 
    ulong mode;  
    ulong cpmap; 
}

DATA [NO_OF_STRUCTS*sizeof(struct DATA)] flowDATA;
```

Input from pipe works but when it comes to fetch individual latest version from the database, I'm outside of my knowledge

I.e. my problem is how to construct the query (code not for terminal) to retrieve the latest inserted data for each array indexposition from the db to compare and if changed, write/insert into db and also inform och what changed back via the pipe.

Feels like I need to add extra fields like an index_no to filter on. 
The query would be like this in below pseudo code (can't get this code correct in my d-code):

```
db.lab.aggregate([{$match {dateadded{$in:["dateadded"]}}.{ $group:{_id:"$name"}}}]);

Select DATA from lab Where LATEST(dateAdded) and index_no == arrayIndex
```

Any ideas?

My testcode init the db like this

```
db.lab.insert([
{"name": "News 1",
 "sektion":2,
 "ptyp":1,
 "mode":1024,
 "cpmap":886,
 dateAdded: new Date()
},{
 "name": "Base 2",
 "sektion":2,
 "ptyp":1,
 "mode":1024,
 "cpmap":886,
 dateAdded: new Date()
},{
 "name": "Name 3",
 "sektion":1,
 "ptyp":3,
 "mode":24,
 "cpmap":886,
 dateAdded: new Date()
},{
 "name": "Name 4",
 "sektion":1,
 "ptyp":1,
 "mode":0,
 "cpmap":1024,
 dateAdded: new Date()
}]};
```

Comment: Why did you use the multiply here? Brought from a C copy paste? `DATA [NO_OF_STRUCTS*sizeof(struct DATA)] flowDATA;`

Comment: Yes I simply copied it into the question and edited to display what I use, I keep a constant to size the array